# How to request permissions in templated apps built for Android Automotive OS?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-automotive

I am trying to make a simple app in Android (13) Automotive OS. My understanding is quite limited, especially with regards to activities. Within the `onGetTemplate`, I hope to ask for a permission, which requires an `Activity` instance. Is it possible to obtain `Activity` from here?

```
class AutoDemoScreen(carContext: CarContext) : Screen(carContext) {
    override fun onGetTemplate(): Template { ... }
}
```

I have tried recursively looking, using `getBaseContext()`, but no `Activity` is to be found. Am I supposed to create a new `Fragment` subclass, and somehow link it to my main screen? I have been looking at some GitHub repositories but it's mostly difficult to parse for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Checkout these links
https://developers.google.com/cars/design/create-apps/sample-flows/grant-permissions-on-phone
https://github.com/android/car-samples/blob/main/car_app_library/places/common/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/sample/places/common/PlacesCarAppService.java#L47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CarContext`'s `requestPermissions(...)` method to request permissions in an app built using the Car App Library. See [Request permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#permissions) for details. If you'd prefer to implement your own permission activity, the [implementation of that method](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/CarContext.java;l=590?q=CarContext) may be a helpful reference for how to do it yourself.

> I have tried recursively looking, using getBaseContext(), but no Activity is to be found.

This is to be expected as the screen code is running as part of a service (your `CarAppService`), not an activity.